# wordpress get_avatar() remove existing class

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I use echo get_avatar(  get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) to display images of users , so as I saw this gives me  tag with its parameters and this tag has class inside it , so I want to completely delete this class , I saw array( 'class' => array( '' ) ) functions like this , but it only add's to existing class ,
 ,
I want to delete completely this class. How can I do this?

Comment: _"I saw array( 'class' => array( '' ) ) functions like this , but it only add's to existing class"_ - guess what, that is what the documentation means by _"additional"_ ... And if you check the actual source code of the function, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/#source, there does not appear to be any filter applied that would allow to modify the class names from the outside. So if you really need this, you will either have to manipulate the returned HTML yourself - or _create_ it without these classes, by basically duplicating the code of this function.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a `get_avatar` filter that supplies the html for the image as the first arg.  You can use `preg_replace` to remove the class attribute like so:

```
add_filter("get_avatar", function($avatar){
    return preg_replace('/class=".*?"/', '', $avatar);
});
```

If you need to remove the default classes and add your own classnames you could do something like this:

```
add_filter("get_avatar", function($avatar){
    return preg_replace('/class=".*?"/', 'class="my-custom-classnames"', $avatar);
});
```